# Php mail $headers break function

Tags: php, email, content-type, oscommerce

I have a function that sends multiple emails out depending on how many products are purchased within oscommerce. It works great until I add in the headers for the php mail() portion of the function. As you can see bellow, my headers read:

```
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  

    $headers .= "From: info@email.com \r\n" .  
           "Reply-To: info@email.com \r\n" .  
           "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
```

But when I declare the headers (which I need in order to send the email as html), only the first email is sent out. Can I not send a header multiple times? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Function snippet:

```
foreach ($dstToProduct as $dsid => $productIndices) {
    $email = $newDropships[$dsid]['email'];
    $subject = "A new order has been placed";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  

    $headers .= "From: info@email.com \r\n" .  
           "Reply-To: info@email.com \r\n" .  
           "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();




    // Build message text
    $date = date('m/d/Y');

    $text = '<table cellpadding="3" style="margin-top: 20px;"><tr style="background-color: #6d7d59; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;"><td style="width: 240px; vertical-align:text-top;">Product Name</td><td style="width: 120px; vertical-align:text-top;">Model Number</td><td style="width: 80px; vertical-align:text-top;">Quantity</td><td style="width: 80px; vertical-align:text-top;">Price</td></tr>';

    foreach ($productIndices as $productIndex) {

            $text .= '<tr style="background-color: #f0f0f0; color: #513311; font-size: 12px;"><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["text"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["model"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["qty"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["price"] . '</td></tr>';

    }

        $text .= '</table>';


    if (!mail($email, $subject, $text, $headers)) {
        mail('info@email.com', 'Error sending product', 'The following order was not sent:&nbsp;' . $order_id);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You get any error (after first mail sent)?

Comment: No error is thrown, nor can I find anything in the error logs. Seems like it just stops the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$subject = "A new order has been placed";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'From: Info <info@email.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: Info <info@email.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .=  "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();   
$date = date('m/d/Y');
foreach ($dstToProduct as $dsid => $productIndices) 
{
 $email = $newDropships[$dsid]['email'];
 $text = '<table cellpadding="3" style="margin-top: 20px;"><tr style="background-color: #6d7d59; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;"><td style="width: 240px; vertical-align:text-top;">Product Name</td><td style="width: 120px; vertical-align:text-top;">Model Number</td><td style="width: 80px; vertical-align:text-top;">Quantity</td><td style="width: 80px; vertical-align:text-top;">Price</td></tr>';

  foreach ($productIndices as $productIndex) {

  $text .= '<tr style="background-color: #f0f0f0; color: #513311; font-size: 12px;"><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["text"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["model"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["qty"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["price"] . '</td></tr>';

  }
 $text .= '</table>';
 if (!mail($email, $subject, $text, $headers)) {
    mail('info@email.com', 'Error sending product', 'The following order was not sent:&nbsp;' . $order_id);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**You can try like this**

Hope it should work for you...

```
 <?php
    $headers=array(
        'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n",
        'From: info@email.com',
        'Content-Type:text/html',
        'Reply-To: info@email.com'
    );
    $subject = "A new order has been placed";

    foreach ($dstToProduct as $dsid => $productIndices) {
        $email = $newDropships[$dsid]['email'];


    // Build message text
        $date = date('m/d/Y');

        $text = '<table cellpadding="3" style="margin-top: 20px;"><tr style="background-color: #6d7d59; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;"><td style="width: 240px; vertical-align:text-top;">Product Name</td><td style="width: 120px; vertical-align:text-top;">Model Number</td><td style="width: 80px; vertical-align:text-top;">Quantity</td><td style="width: 80px; vertical-align:text-top;">Price</td></tr>';

        foreach ($productIndices as $productIndex) {

        $text .= '<tr style="background-color: #f0f0f0; color: #513311; font-size: 12px;"><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["text"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["model"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["qty"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["price"] . '</td></tr>';

        }

        $text .= '</table>';   
        $body = $text;


    if (!mail($email,$subject,$body,implode("\r\n",$headers))) {
            mail('info@email.com', 'Error sending product', 'The following order was not sent:&nbsp;' . $order_id);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If are you thinking that the phpversion() rise the problem, try something like this:

```
    $phpV =  phpversion();
    $subject = "A new order has been placed";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  
    $headers .= "From: info@email.com \r\n" .  
                "Reply-To: info@email.com \r\n" .  
                "X-Mailer: PHP/" .$phpV;
```

And generally, you don't need to do this every time, the variables that is not specific user depends - you can declare once. something like this:

```
$subject = "A new order has been placed";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  

$headers .= "From: info@email.com \r\n" .  
       "Reply-To: info@email.com \r\n" .  
       "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

$date = date('m/d/Y');

$text = '<table cellpadding="3" style="margin-top: 20px;"><tr style="background-color: #6d7d59; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;"><td style="width: 240px; vertical-align:text-top;">Product Name</td><td style="width: 120px; vertical-align:text-top;">Model Number</td><td style="width: 80px; vertical-align:text-top;">Quantity</td><td style="width: 80px; vertical-align:text-top;">Price</td></tr>';
foreach ($productIndices as $productIndex) {
    $text .= '<tr style="background-color: #f0f0f0; color: #513311; font-size: 12px;"><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' 
    . $products_array[$productIndex]["text"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">'
    . $products_array[$productIndex]["model"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' 
    . $products_array[$productIndex]["qty"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">'
    . $products_array[$productIndex]["price"] . '</td></tr>';
}
$text .= '</table>';

foreach ($dstToProduct as $dsid => $productIndices) {
    $email = $newDropships[$dsid]['email'];
    if (!mail($email, $subject, $text, $headers)) {
        mail('info@email.com', 'Error sending product', 'The following order was not sent: ' . $order_id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your $headers is merging with the loop, try this. I am sure it will work:

```
foreach ($dstToProduct as $dsid => $productIndices) {
    $email = $newDropships[$dsid]['email'];
    $subject = "A new order has been placed";

    $headers = ""; 

    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  

    $headers .= "From: info@email.com \r\n" .  
           "Reply-To: info@email.com \r\n" .  
           "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();




    // Build message text
    $date = date('m/d/Y');

    $text = '<table cellpadding="3" style="margin-top: 20px;"><tr style="background-color: #6d7d59; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;"><td style="width: 240px; vertical-align:text-top;">Product Name</td><td style="width: 120px; vertical-align:text-top;">Model Number</td><td style="width: 80px; vertical-align:text-top;">Quantity</td><td style="width: 80px; vertical-align:text-top;">Price</td></tr>';

    foreach ($productIndices as $productIndex) {

            $text .= '<tr style="background-color: #f0f0f0; color: #513311; font-size: 12px;"><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["text"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["model"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["qty"] . '</td><td style="vertical-align:text-top;">' . $products_array[$productIndex]["price"] . '</td></tr>';

    }

        $text .= '</table>';


    if (!mail($email, $subject, $text, $headers)) {
        mail('info@email.com', 'Error sending product', 'The following order was not sent:&nbsp;' . $order_id);
    }

}
}
```